# How can I update my existing world map in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been playing on a world since 1.6.4 and I have quite a bit of stuff built up (a massive subway network, a castle, a huge village, etc) and I don't want to start a new map, but I haven't seen anything from the new updates.  No horses, painted deserts, or nary a new flower anywhere to be seen.

Is there a way to update my world map so that it'll include the new stuff into it?  I'm playing single player locally.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you using any mods? As for horses, the wiki says they only spawn in plains and savannas.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These new biomes will only spawn in freshly generated, brand new terrain. Anywhere you've ever been before will be already generated.

What I'd recommend is going a few hundred blocks away by Nether. Every 1 block in the Nether is equal to 8 in the overworld, so you can get 8x further away in the same amount of time.

Keep looking. Horses are relatively rare and can only spawn in plains/savannahs. The mesa/flower forest/other new biomes have a fairly low spawn rate, so even if you go far away it could take a while to find.

If you have updated your Minecraft to the newest version (currently 1.11.2) by using the launcher, it's just a matter of looking hard enough to find the stuff you need, in areas you haven't even loaded yet.

Answer (score 0):

When you update your world to 1.7.5-1.7.6, any unloaded chunks will spawn with 1.7 terrain. When this happens you often get walls of terrain on the edge of unloaded chunks. If you don't want this effect to happen near your creations, walk/fly out in every direction and load new chunks until you see fit. Then, backup a save file of the world just in case, then update to minecraft 1.7 Hope this helps!